# modificar arreglo dentro de otro arreglo JAVA

Tags: java

he creado clase **Bibloteca** con un nombre y un arreglo de la clase **Libros** como atributos, en la clase **Libros** están los nombres, autor, etc como atributos.

**Y aquí están los objetos de cada clase, una bibloteca de arreglo que contiene una bibloteca, y un arreglo de 5 libros de la clase Libros**

```html
static Libros libro[]=new Libros[5];
static Bibloteca bib[]=new Bibloteca[1];
```

Creo una biblioteca con 5 libros.

```
public void crear_libro(Bibloteca bib[],Libros libro[]){

        bib[0]=new Bibloteca("Zancrow");
        bib[0].ingresar_libro(new Libros("Sthephen King","It",321,150.99));
        bib[0].ingresar_libro(new Libros("Frank Herbert","Dune",400,236.99));
        bib[0].ingresar_libro(new Libros("","Call of the Cthullu",200,70.99));
        bib[0].ingresar_libro(new Libros("Jean-Paul Sartre","El ser y la nada",142,63.99));
        bib[0].ingresar_libro(new Libros("H.P Lovecraft","Necronomicon",220,92.99));   
    }
```

el método **crear_libro** funciona bien ya lo he probado, y para comprobar si esta bien he creado un método para mostrar estos libros con bucles anidados.

```html
public void mostrar_libros(Bibloteca bib[],Libros libro[]){
        for (int i=0;i<bib.length;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<libro.length;j++){
                System.out.println("Autor: "+bib[i].getLibros(j).getAutor());
                System.out.println("Titulo: "+bib[i].getLibros(j).getTitulo());
                System.out.println("Numero de Paginas: "+bib[i].getLibros(j).getNumPag());
                System.out.println("Precio: "+bib[i].getLibros(j).getPrecio());
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }
```

ahora creo un metodo que su funcion es encontrar aquel libro que no tiene autor.

```
public void autor_default(Bibloteca bib[],Libros libro[]){
        
        for (int i=0;i<bib.length;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<libro.length;j++){
                if (bib[i].getLibros(j).getAutor().equals("")){
                    bib[i]=new Bibloteca(bib[i].getNombre());
                    //Libros libro1=new Libros("H.P Lovecraft","Call of the Cthullu",200,70.99);
                    bib[i].getLibros(j).setAutor("H.P Lovecraft");
                    bib[i].getLibros(j).setTitulo("Call of the Cthullu");
                    bib[i].getLibros(j).setNumPag(200);
                    bib[i].getLibros(j).setPrecio(70.99);
                    //bib[i].ingresar_libro(new Libros(libro1));
                }
            }
        }    
    }
```

a este libro le defino esos valores para guardarlos.

Lo que sucede es que me tira error porque biblioteca[i].getLibros(j) es null, porque es null cuando yo le asigne el iterador **[j] a libro de la clase Libros** que contiene ese libro en particular pero no me encuentra ese libro porque ese método devolver libro es null cuando no lo es.

Por otro lado lo que esta comentado es otro intento pero que también es erróneo.

En otras palabras lo que quiero hacer es modificar objetos ya creados en un arreglo, pero claro el objeto que cumpla esa función **if** del método **autor_default**

Comment: Hay cosas que no sabemos que son.. que es Biblioteca? que hace ingresar libro? porque a crear_libro le pasas un parametro que no usas? tu medoto autor_default recorre dos cosas totalmente diferentes y trata de acceder a posiciones diferentes de cosas diferentes.. que tratabas de hacer ahi? Ojo.. mucho de lo que te pregunto, lo podes solucionar haciendo debug de tu codigo

Comment: No se que tamaño tiene tu arreglo de bib, pero si declaraste el arreglo con más de un elemento, pero SOLO creaste una biblioteca (la de la posición 0), obviamente cuando llegue al segundo elemento bib[1]  la cosa va a explotar, porque no hay nada ahí. De ahí que obtengas una NPE.

Comment: Bibloteca y Libros son clases dentro de la lcase Bibliteca he creado un arreglo de libros, he creado un objeto de arrgelo[1] en Bibloteca porques es una Bibloteca solo que contiene 5 libros, arreglo de clase Libros[5].

Como pueden ver metodo de crear libros esta bien lo he probado, tambien tengo otro metodo para mostrar los libros y bibloteca con bucles anidados y funciona, el problema es querer modificar esos libros ya creados ese es mi problema.gbianchi

Comment: que version de java usas?